# Update a graph from chartsjs in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I have an graph with some data in it. When I click on the button the data should change + the graph. It works but... when you hover on the graph the graph with the first data will flicker some times. I have no idea why.

Example :
https://codesandbox.io/s/zx6o9wj654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because, you are creating a new chart instance each time the *submit* button is clicked.

To get it working properly, you need to [destroy](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/api.html#destroy) the previous chart instance, before creating a new one, like so :

```
...
createData = () => {
      // destroy previous chart instance, if exists
      if (this.myChart) this.myChart.destroy();
      /** create new chart instance **/
      const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
      // store chart instance to a class property
      this.myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
         ...
```

here is the [**working example**](https://codesandbox.io/s/vymv5wr6w0).